# Write a .txt with values of three listboxes

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I have to export a .txt file with the values of three listboxes per each row. I've tried to to this with the following code:

```
Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    For Each o As String In Form10.ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Zip(Form10.ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of Object).Zip(Form6.ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of Object)), Function(x1, x2, x3) CStr(x1) & "," & CStr(x2) & "," & CStr(x3))
        writer.WriteLine(o)
    Next
End Using
```

I'm receiving several errors:

```
Error   BC36646 Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function Zip(Of TSecond, TResult)(second As IEnumerable(Of TSecond), resultSelector As Func(Of Object, TSecond, TResult)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'Enumerable' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
Error   BC36586 Argument not specified for parameter 'resultSelector' of extension method 'Public Function Zip(Of TSecond, TResult)(second As IEnumerable(Of TSecond), resultSelector As Func(Of Object, TSecond, TResult)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'Enumerable'.
Error   BC42020 Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.
```

---

Unfortunately, while Form10.Listbox1 and Form10.Listbox2 are meant to be of the same size, Form6.Listbox6 is smaller; so the file I need to be exported should be with the following format:
F10.LB1,F10.LB2,F6.LB2 - for the lenght of Form6.Listbox6 and the F10.LB1,F10.LB2 for the rest of the items. If you need more explanations, please comment or answer. Thanks all are going to write me here. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :**

```
  Using writer = New StreamWriter("d:\test.txt")

            For id As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

                Dim to_write As String = ListBox1.Items(id) + "," + ListBox2.Items(id)

                If (ListBox3.Items.Count -1 >= id ) Then
                    to_write += "," + ListBox3.Items(id)
                End If

                writer.WriteLine(to_write)

            Next

        End Using
```

*Dont forget Count -1 ;if you have 5 items : 0 to 4 = 5 items.*

---

Are you ok with this way :

```
  Using writer = New StreamWriter("d:\test.txt")
            For Each o As String In ListBox1.Items
                writer.WriteLine(o)
            Next
            For Each o As String In ListBox2.Items
                writer.WriteLine(o)
            Next
            For Each o As String In ListBox3.Items
                writer.WriteLine(o)
            Next
        End Using
```

Or for all listboxes :

```
  Using writer = New StreamWriter("d:\test.txt")

            For Each lbx As ListBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ListBox)

                For Each o As String In lbx.Items
                    writer.WriteLine(o)
                Next

            Next

        End Using
```

Comment: Ok and in the format you wrote, how coud I separe values with commas?

Comment: With what way ?
Do you have an example of what you want ?

Comment: The format should be such as 1,2,3 where 1 is the value of LB1, 2 of LB2 and 3 of LB3, for a number of lines equals to the size of LB3. For the other lines the format is 1,2, because LB1 and LB2 are of the same size but LB3 is smaller than the other

Comment: Just debugged and it's what I'm exactly looking for.

Comment: Glad to help you !
I just edited one little thing : **If (ListBox3.Items.Count -1 >= id ) Then** 
It looks better than If (ListBox3.Items.Count >= id +1) Then